# MX records mailgun and gsuite /gmail. Using a subdomain on mailgun = Adding a subdomain on my WP hoster (siteground)?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, dns, mailgun

I want to handle transactional emails with mailgun.
AND use gsuite as my "normal" business email provider.

On every mailgun support page you see this message:

Warning

Do not configure Receiving MX DNS records if you already have another provider handling inbound mail delivery for your domain (e.g. Gmail). Instead we recommend using a subdomain on Mailgun (e.g. mg.yourdomain.com)

Okay, so I have set up a subdomain called mail.mydomain.com at mailgun.
Everything is verified except the MX records. I left them blank.
As a result: The transactional emails are send but they are received as SPAM (with gmail and yahoo)
gmx did NOT receive the emails.

So I'm wondering: How do I tackle this MX problem?
Do I have to set up the mailgun subdomain mail.mydomain.com at my WP hoster (siteground in my case) as well to make it work? 
Do I have to go to CPanel and add a subdomain and then can use different MX records that won't get in conflict with gmail/gsuite (as my business email)?

Nor siteground nor mailgun couldn't really give me an answer:(

At this point I'm thinking of just using gsuite also as my smtp transactional woocommerce provider. I guess 130 emails/day are sufficient and there will be no conflicts while setting it up with WP mail SMTP.

Do you actually use mailgun for transactional email and gsuite as your "normal" business email provider?
And how do I set this up correctly?

Help would very much be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I use Mailgun for several domains that also have email associated with the domain. The key is to set up Mailgun using a subdomain as you did.

You will need to add the MX records to your DNS. Since you should set those up with the host as your subdomain, then these should not interfere with your email setup.

Here is an example of how those records should look when added to Google domains. Note that the host is set to be `mg` which is the subdomain in this case. In your case, this would be `mail`.

[image]

Comment: thank you Marc for your explanation:) can I ask two followups: 1)I'm still not sure if I have to go to my hoster (siteground), where I've installed WP, log into CPanel and add "physically" the subdomain "mail.mydomain.com"? 2) the second question is: the graphic with the MX and TXT records above is a screenshot from your your WP hoster?

Comment: I think I've got it. I've added a subdomain on my WP hoster (without a physical folder) and were able to set the MX settings there finally... on mailgun's site I have green checkmarks! thank you...

Comment: I ran some tests with different email providers as customers... woocommerce transactional emails with customers at yahoo.com and at outlook.com end up straight in their spam/junk folder! gmail and gmx seemed to work and land correctly in the inbox... do you face the same issue or were you able to fix it? I'm not sure if it is a mailgun issue or if I didn't set up the plugin WP mail SMTP correctly...

Comment: You could try using the Mailgun WordPress plugin to rule out WP Mail SMTP and use the Mailgun API. https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailgun/ If you still see these issues, log into Mailgun and look to see if there is anything in the logs that looks off.

Comment: I had the same spam issues with the mailgun plugin... i switched to gsuite and set up an api there... working great, every email I checked ends up in the INBOX :) the sending limits are more restrict, only 100/day if I understand their documentation right (api/smtp)...